# C++ Basic Menu Driven Program

Tags: c++

I have a question that should be simple but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I have a menu driven C++ program that works perfectly when the menu options are numbers but I can't figure out how to change the numbers to letters.

For example:

works fine when choices are 1, 2, or 3 but not A, B, C.

Not sure how I am supposed to declare the option... is it a char?  thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Variables needed for the problem
    int numbServCharge; //number of service charges
    char choice; //menu choice
    double transAmt, balence, totalServCharge; //transaction amount, current balence, total service charges

    //Constant service change
    const double servCharge = 0.25; //constant $0.25 for service charges

    numbServCharge = 0; //Start the counter for number of service charges at zero
    cout << "Checkbook Balencing Program\n\n";
    cout << "Enter the beginning balence:  "; 
    cin >> balence; //get the initial balence
    cout << endl;

    do
    {
        //Highlight menu options
        cout << "\nCommands\n";
        cout << "C - process a check\n";
        cout << "D - process a deposit\n";
        cout << "E - end the program\n\n";

        //Get user's choice from menu
        cout << "Enter transaction type:  ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;

        //Create an error message for invalid choice and get a second choice
        while((choice != 'C') && (choice != 'D') && (choice != 'E')
        {
            cout << "Invalid selection.  Please choose C, D or E: ";
            cin >> choice;
        }

        //Set up for option #1 -- using a check
        if(choice=='C')
        {
            cout << "Enter transaction amount:  ";
            cin >> transAmt; //Get the amount of the check
            cout << "\nProcessing check for $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << transAmt;
            transAmt = transAmt + servCharge; //Add the service charge onto the transaction
            numbServCharge++; //Add one to the number of service charges there have been
            balence = balence - transAmt; //Update account balence
            cout << "\nBalence:  $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << balence;
            cout << "\nService charge:  $0.25 for a check\n";
            totalServCharge = servCharge * numbServCharge; //Update total cost of service charges
            cout << "Total service charges:  $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << totalServCharge << endl; //Tell user total service charges so far
        }

        //Set up for option #2 -- deposits
        if(choice=='D')
        {
            cout << "Enter transaction amout:  ";
            cin >> transAmt; //Get the amount of the deposit
            cout << "\nProcessing Deposit for $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << transAmt << endl;
            transAmt = transAmt - servCharge; //Add the service charge onto the deposit
            numbServCharge++; //Add one to the number of service charges there have been
            balence = balence + transAmt; //Update account balence
            cout << "Balence:  $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << balence << endl;
            totalServCharge = servCharge * numbServCharge; //Update total cost of service charges
            cout << "Total service charges:  $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << totalServCharge << endl; //Tell user total service charges so far
    }

    }while(choice != 'E'); //Close program if option 3 is selected

    //Display final balence
    cout << "Processing end of the month";
    cout << "\nFinal balence :  $  " << fixed << setprecision(2) << balence << endl << endl;

    system("pause"); //Pause screen so it doesn't close right away
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "works" and "doesn't work"?

Comment: Uppercase and lowercase letters are different. You should test for both in your conditions

Comment: Tested and it works just fine. Maybe you forgot to rebuild the program?

Comment: @Caesar What logic issue? The program compiles and that's the only thing that can be understood by "works" when there's no other description of the problem. I even tested "C" and "E" and managed to select an option.

Comment: A Stack Overflow question should never contain the words "works perfectly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing for a string, you should convert everything to a common case. In you case you should convert the user input to upper case. You can do this by using [toupper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) function

Here is the bit of code you need to change to make your program work

```
cout << "Enter transaction type:  ";
cin >> choice;
choice = toupper(choice); // Change Here
cout << endl;
```

Comment: That's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once you change `while((choice != 'C') && (choice != 'D') && (choice != 'E')` to `while((choice != 'C') && (choice != 'D') && (choice != 'E'))`, your code runs well.  Although I would have personally used a `std::string` instead of a `char`.

Granted, Caesar's answer is a valid point - and I would change that as well.  However, it would be better as a comment because it doesn't resolve the problem.  Wait, hold on.  What problem?  Your program seems to still "run perfectly" even with the alphabetic menu options.

The only bug in your program is when you try and assign `balence` (or any of your three `double`s) to a non-numeric entry.  When I type "C" for initial balance, I see this monstrosity:

[image: That's interesting.]

Over and over and over.  That's not fun.  Similar thing happens if I type a letter for transaction amount:

[image: Also interesting.]

Solution: Never try to jam input taken directly from the user into a variable that is not a type of string.  Use a built in string-to-number function like [`atof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/), or *(much preferred)* add error handlers like this:

```
if (std::cin >> dbl)
{
    //input is a double. handle that here.
}
else
{
    //input isn't a double. handle that here.
}
```

By the way, it's spelled balance, not balence ;)